# How do I import modules or install extensions in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import several modules that come bundled with postgres, and all the commands to do so (such as contrib.import etc) do not work or cannot be found.

Answer (score 92):

To install PostgreSQL `contrib` modules on Ubuntu or Kubuntu (or similar Linux distributions):

1. Install the contrib package:
   `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib`
2. Change to the database owner account (e.g., `postgres`).
3. `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";`

If you are trying to install non-"trusted" modules, you need to be a superuser to install them. Otherwise, you only need to have CREATE privilege on the database you are trying to use the module on.

For versions before 9.1, do step #1 above, and then:

1. Restart the database:
   `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 restart`
2. Change to the database owner account (e.g., `postgres`).
3. Change to the contrib modules' directory:
   `/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/`
4. Use `ls` to see a list of the following modules:

   ```
    adminpack               autoinc
    btree_gin               btree_gist
    chkpass                 citext
    cube                    dblink
    dict_int                dict_xsyn
    earthdistance           fuzzystrmatch
    hstore                  insert_username
    int_aggregate           isn
    lo                      ltree
    moddatetime             pageinspect
    pg_buffercache          pgcrypto
    pg_freespacemap         pgrowlocks
    pg_stat_statements      pgstattuple
    pg_trgm                 pgxml
    refint                  seg
    sslinfo                 tablefunc
    test_parser             timetravel
    tsearch2                uuid-ossp
   ```
5. Load the SQL files using:
   `psql -U user_name -d database_name -f module_name.sql`

For example, if your administrative user was named `postgres` and your database was named `storage` and the module you wanted was `cube`, you would type:

```
psql -U postgres -d storage -f cube.sql
```

Comment: In postgresql 9.1 on ubuntu the modules are in `/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension` and you have to use [CREATE EXTENSION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html) to install them.

Answer (score 7):

1. login as postgres user
2. use create extension to load it

I have a database named 'book' for example,

psql -U postgres book

create extension cube

Repeat for each extension required, then \q to logouy

Comment: The script syntax is incorrect, would have to be `psql -U postgres book -c "create extension cube"`. And `CREATE EXTENSION` was introduced with Postgres 9.1. This question is about 8.4.

Comment: Those looking for help for PostgreSQL 9.1+ for 7 Databases in 7 weeks should find this useful.

Comment: Can confirm this method works for loading tablefunc extension for postgres 10.13 and helped me to avoid giving SUPERUSER privileges to a regular user.