# How do I import modules or install extensions in PostgreSQL 9.1+?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

**Firstly, if you're not using 9.1+, please [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1564056/124486).**

How do I install an extension to PostgreSQL 9.1?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Postgrseql 9.1 provides for a new command [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html). You should use it to install modules.

[Modules provided in 9.1 can be found here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html). The include,

```
adminpack , auth_delay , auto_explain , btree_gin , btree_gist
, chkpass , citext , cube , dblink , dict_int
, dict_xsyn , dummy_seclabel , earthdistance , file_fdw , fuzzystrmatch
, hstore , intagg , intarray , isn , lo
, ltree , oid2name , pageinspect , passwordcheck , pg_archivecleanup
, pgbench , pg_buffercache , pgcrypto , pg_freespacemap , pgrowlocks
, pg_standby , pg_stat_statements , pgstattuple , pg_test_fsync , pg_trgm
, pg_upgrade , seg , sepgsql , spi , sslinfo , tablefunc
, test_parser , tsearch2 , unaccent , uuid-ossp , vacuumlo
, xml2
```

If for instance you wanted to install [`earthdistance`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/earthdistance.html), simply use this command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;
```

If you wanted to install an extension with a hyphen in its name, like `uuid-ossp`, you need to enclose the extension name in double quotes:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

- [Read more about contrib, and the modules available in 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib.html).
- [Read about the new extension infrastructure, and the SQL commands to manage it here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html) You can now more easily uninstall a module, see `DROP EXTENSION`. You can also get an extension list, and there is basic support for version numbers.

Comment: For convenience, to remove an extension:         

`DROP EXTENSION extension_name [, ...]`

Answer (score 63):

While Evan Carrol's answer is correct, please note that you need to install the postgresql contrib package in order for the CREATE EXTENSION command to work.

In Ubuntu 12.04 it would go like this:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Restart the postgresql server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

All available extension are in:

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/
```

Now you can run the CREATE EXTENSION command.

Comment: I was trying to install citext, but google was not finding this page, and this answer did not come up.  Now citext is mentioned three times on this page :-)  Come on google, do that indexing thing.

Comment: Note that the package is also needed to add `vacuumlo` script in pgsql bin. Additionally you might need to use `ln -s` to link vacuumlo to `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the extensions which are maintained and provided by the core PostgreSQL development team, there are extensions available from third parties.  Notably, there is a site dedicated to that purpose: http://www.pgxn.org/

Answer (score 10):

**For the postgrersql10**

I have solved it with

```
yum install postgresql10-contrib
```

Don't forget to activate extensions in postgresql.conf

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

then of course restart

```
systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
```

all of the needed extensions you can find here

```
/usr/pgsql-10/share/extension/
```

Answer (score 5):

The extensions available for each version of Postgresql vary. An easy way to check which extensions are available is, as has been already mentioned:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;
```

If the extension that you are looking for is available, you can install it using:

```
CREATE EXTENSION 'extensionName';
```

or if you want  to drop it use:

```
DROP EXTENSION 'extensionName';
```

With `psql` you can additionally check if the extension has been successfully installed using `\dx`, and find more details about the extension using `\dx+ extensioName`. It returns additional information about the extension, like which packages are used with it.

If the extension is not available in your Postgres version, then you need to download the necessary binary files and libraries and locate it them at `/usr/share/conrib`

Comment: Leave off the quotes. This works: `create extension intarray;` This does *not*: `create extension 'intarray';`

Answer (score 0):

Into psql terminal put:

```
\i <path to contrib files>
```

in ubuntu it usually is `/usr/share/postgreslq/<your pg version>/contrib/<contrib file>.sql`

Comment: That's for pre 9.1. Do not use this method in 9.1+.

Answer (score 0):

How to download and install if you have SUSE. As an example I am downloading the tablefunc module so I can use crosstab. I have PostgreSQL 9.6.1.

right-click desktop, terminal, type:

```
sudo zypper in postgreql-contrib
```

Enter credentials, continue by typing:

```
y
```

Run query (I ran mine from pgAdminIII):

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

You should now have the `crosstab` function.

I did not have to restart.