# getting error function lo_manage() does not exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

Currently i am using PostgreSQL Plus Advance Server 9.3 and i just created a table which has a column of blob type and i am using oid data type to store blob value.

Now i want to create a BEFORE UPDATE AND DELETE TRIGGER to remove the orphan data from pg_largeobject table of postgresql using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEL_OID BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON INFO_LOB
 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lo_manage (BLOB_VALUE_);
```

But when i am trying to execute this trigger,
Getting error:

```
ERROR: function lo_manage() does not exist
SQL state: 42883
```

so i am not able to understand that what is the mistake that i am doing. can somebody please help me? thanks

Comment: `lo_manage()` function is added with the `lo` contrib module. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo.html -- have you added this module by executing `CREATE EXTENSION lo;` ?

Comment: What pozs wrote, or you don't have the schema where the extension is installed in your [`search_path`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).

Comment: Hi @pozs thanks for your reply, i got my answer, actually i don't have created the extension, now it is working.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql/13264961#13264961, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025515/how-do-i-import-modules-or-install-extensions-in-postgresql-9-1-9-2-9-3-9-4/9025551