# Missing Functions after install of Postgis 2.1

Tags: postgresql, postgis, levenshtein-distance

I have taken over a site that I did not build. The database is all messed up, and I am reloading the database from a schema dump file. The database also includes postgis 2.1.

I am using:

- Postgresql 9.3
- CentOS 6.5
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Ruby on Rails 3

The problem I am having is that the old database has 702 functions in the database for postgis, but my newly created database has only 562 functions. I need some of the missing functions, such as `levenstein`.

Neither the `postgis.sql` nor the `spatial_ref_sys.sql` files include these functions.

How can i install the missing 140 functions? I can not see a way to dump the old functions into a backup without backing up the entire database - but like I said, it is messed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like `levenstein` are included in the [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) module. If you're using Postgres 9.1 or above, you can use [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html). This answer may also be of some use:

[How do I import modules or install extensions in PostgreSQL 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025515/how-do-i-import-modules-or-install-extensions-in-postgresql-9-1-9-2-9-3-9-4)

Sadly, it sounds like you'll need to work out which other modules were being used, but Google is your friend there.